# Multi-level modeling with repeated measures condition using R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to do stat. analysis for data with repeated measures

The data is consists of:

```
+--------------+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| Participants | Device  | State  | Activity | Values |
+--------------+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| P1           | Device1 | State0 | Rest     |      9 |
| P1           | Device1 | State0 | Typing   |     15 |
| P1           | Device1 | State1 | Rest     |      8 |
| P1           | Device1 | State1 | Typing   |     19 |
| P1           | Device2 | State0 | Rest     |      9 |
| P1           | Device2 | State0 | Typing   |     15 |
| P1           | Device2 | State1 | Rest     |      8 |
| P1           | Device2 | State1 | Typing   |     19 |
+--------------+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| P2           | Device1 | State0 | Rest     |      9 |
| P2           | Device1 | State0 | Typing   |     15 |
| P2           | Device1 | State1 | Rest     |      8 |
| P2           | Device1 | State1 | Typing   |     19 |
| P2           | Device3 | State0 | Rest     |      9 |
| P2           | Device3 | State0 | Typing   |     15 |
| P2           | Device3 | State1 | Rest     |      8 |
| P2           | Device3 | State1 | Typing   |     19 |
+--------------+---------+--------+----------+--------+
```

- Participants: identifier of a participant
- Device: the device they wore
- State: some experimental state
- Activity: some experimental activity
- Values: data collected from device

Each participant wore a set of devices at the same time. During experiments, they wore Device1 and one device from the others (e.g., Device2 and 3). Then, they performed all pairs of state-activity (e.g., state0-Rest, state0-Typing, State1-Rest, State1-Typing). Some values from two devices were collected.

What I want is to check there is different between values of Device 1 and the other devices, according to states and activities. For this, I modeled it like R formula below:

```
model <- lmer(Values ~ Device + (1 | State) + (1 |Activity) + (1 | Participants), data = data)
```

I heard that repeated-measure settings belong to crossed configuration, so I treated State and Activity as a random effect, but I can't convince it. Am I right? please correct the formula if there is any problem.

Comment: If there are only two levels for State and Activity I would have thought fitting them as random effects would be quite tricky so I would have gone for fixed instead but the underlying science is not clear to me.